# Introductory text on perturbation theory for dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

I am working on my thesis which is about oscillations and as far as I realise I need to know about perturbation theory and methods in solving differential equations, specifically dynamical systems. A Googling returned the following results:

- http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111178
- http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Perturbation_theory_(dynamical_systems)
- http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~eve2/reg_pert.pdf
- http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5700-4

Does anybody have any suggestion? First one seems reasonable but I am not sure about the quality. Second and third one is very general. Forth one is only about finite dimensional linear operators and quite long. What I am looking for is a concise and short introductory text for perturbation theory in Dynamical Systems.

Comment: Mark Holmes' book is good and pretty elementry. J.K. Kevorkian is more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Ref. 4 has nothing to do with the perturbation theory you are looking for. Second and third are general reviews, without almost any details.

If you are interested specifically in dynamical systems and ODE, I would recommend to get a copy of Verhulst's [Nonlinear Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540609342). It provides a good description of ODE theory, and has several chapters on perturbation theory. And it is written in really intuitive way, an ideal applied second ODE course.

Answer (score 0):

Verhulst has co-authored 3 authoritative books on perturbation of ODEs and (some) PDEs.

The basic material and overview is in :1) Nonlinear DIff. Eq and Dynamical systems.

The complete averaging research level book is : 2) Averaging methods in nonlinear dynamical systems

For singular perturbations in ODEs and PDEs: 3) Methods and applications of singular perturbations